# How to overlay a div with a link onto an image

Tags: html, css

I have a grid system built for all of my images. I am looking to overlay each image with a different background color and a link to another page, when the mouse goes over it. The name of the web page would also overlay on top of the image.

```
 <div class="row1">
     <div id="one" class="column1">
      <a href="#"><img id="chaos" src="" alt="">
     <div class="overlay"> 
     <div class="text">Our Games</div>
     </div></a>
   </div>

   <div class="column1">
     <a href="#"><img id="dragon" src="" alt="">
     <div class="overlay">
       <div class="text">Origin Story</div>
   </div></a>

  <img id="logo" src="" alt="">

     <a href="#"></a><img id="dice" src="" alt="">
       <div class="overlay">
       <div class="text">Contact Us</div>
     </div></a>
  </div>  

  <div class="column1">
     <a href="#"></a><img id="thunder" src="" alt="">
     <div class="overlay">
       <div class="text">Email Sign Up</div>
     </div></a>
  </div> 
</div>
```

This is the CSS that I am using. The problem is it only does one overlay for the very first image and the overlay only happens when the mouse is on the very bottom of the image. It also does a big overlay over all images and not just over the one image the mouse is over.

```
     #dragon {
      height: 200px;
     }
    #chaos {
     height: 600px;
    }
   #logo {
    height: 150px;
   }
   #thunder {
     height: 600px;
   }
   #dice {
     height: 235px;
   }

   /*--------------grid for images --------------------------*/

   * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }
  body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
 }
.row1 {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
 }
 .column1 {
  -ms-flex: 33.33%;
  flex: 33.33%;
  max-width: 33.33%;
  padding: 0 4px;
 }
 .column1 img {
   margin-top: 8px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 100%;
 }
 /*--------------overlay for links--------------------------------*/


  .overlay {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     opacity: 0;
     transition: .5s ease;
     background-color: black;
   } 
   #one:hover .overlay {
     opacity: 1;
   }
   .text {
     color: white;
     font-size: 20px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     text-align: center;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the z-index: 1; tag in css

Answer (score 0):

This is your issue:

```
.overlay {
     //styles...
     opacity: 0;
     //more styles..
}
#one:hover .overlay {
     opacity: 1;
}
```

Which means set opacity to 1 (visible) when hovering over element with ID "one" for element with class "overlay"
And initial opacity is 0

The issue with it being big is because it has

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
```

but parent element is missing

```
position:relative;
```

Comment: Wow that was a simple easy fix that solved my issue, thanks for that!